# QTimer isn't calling myfunction as expected

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtimer

In the code below the first function gets called but the second function doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
def time_cursor_plot(self):       
    print 'function called'
    t = QtCore.QTimer()
    t.setInterval(1000)
    t.timeout.connect(self.start_timer)        
    t.start()

def start_timer(self):
    print ' this one too'
```

Comment: You're allowing the timer to be garbage-collected.

Comment: Your code example makes no sense...have you changed method names? What is the `start_timer()` method doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method start_timer is in the same class? otherwise remove "self".

```
def time_cursor_plot(self):       
    print 'function called'
    t = QtCore.QTimer()
    t.setInterval(1000)
    t.timeout.connect(start_timer)
    t.start()

def start_timer(self):
    print ' this one too'
```

Comment: self is a reference to the class instance